# Unit Test Parametric Abstract Factory

Tags: unit-testing, abstract-factory

Consider the following design:

```
public class PhoneAbstractFactory
{
        public IPhoneFactory GetPhoneFactory(string type, bool needSmartPhone)
        {
            if (type == "Samsung")
                return new SamsungFactory(needSmartPhone);

            if (type == "Apple")
                return new AppleFactory(needSmartPhone);

            else throw new Exception("Unknown phone type: " + type);
        }
}

    public interface IPhoneFactory  { }

    public class SamsungFactory : IPhoneFactory
    {
        public SamsungFactory(bool needSmartPhone)
        {
        }
    }

    public class AppleFactory : IPhoneFactory
    {
        public AppleFactory(bool needSmartPhone)
        {
        }
    }
```

How can I test only `PhoneAbstactFactory` ? If I want to test it, inevitably an instance of either `AppleFactory` or `SamsungFactory` should get be instantiated; which means that if the test is to be passed, it is needed that constructing both of the factories must be always assumed truth-worthy. Otherwise, test scope spans over the two factories which is not good.

Comment: what's the problem with returning the actual instance? surely your test wants to basically check that when the string is "Samsung" the `IPhoneFactory` that is returned is an instance of `SamsungFactory`? How else are you going to test it?

Comment: @SamHolder The problem is that in this way not only `PhoneAbstractFactory` is tested but also `SamsungFactory' is tested as well. This is not a **unit** test

Comment: @Hans, imho that's not entirely true, you are of course testing that the factory gets you the correct type of object. Thus implicitly that object will be created, but it does not test the logic of the factory, you can do absurd things in the constructor, the test will pass as long as there is no exception.

Comment: @AD.Net So how can I somehow shortcut construction of the inner objects? I mean how can I make the constructors do absurd things (as you said) just to let the test work?

Comment: @Hans, those tests would be part of the tests for the class itself, not the factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are being too dogmatic about you definition of unit test.

In the end the job of a factory class is to produce an instance of a class. In order to test that it must create that other class.

A unit test does not necessarily test a single class but a [unit of functionality or behavior](http://artofunittesting.com/definition-of-a-unit-test/) (not the authour of the book linked doesn't say it tests one class, but one logical concept which:

> can span a single method, a whole class or multiple classes working together to achieve one single logical purpose that can be verified`

). This may involve several classes. Doing otherwise will end up with very brittle tests which must be changed every time the code is refactored, out tests which attempt to mock or stub every interaction with another class and this ends up jumping through ridiculous hoops (as you are trying to do here)

Be pragmatic. Test the **behavior** you want you class to exhibit and do this in a way that if the implementation changes your tests won't have to, as far as possible. You'll make your life a lot easier both now and in the future.

Comment: Convinced. Thanks for shedding light

Comment: Unfortunately, this clarification is not present in the book; hence the result the author complemented in his website